# Erro ao instalar pacotes com npm Node.Js

Tags: node.js, npm

```js
** gyp ERR!find Python
gyp ERR!find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR!find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR!find Python checking
if "python"
can be used
gyp ERR!find Python - executable path is "C:\Users\Rog�rio Chaves\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"
gyp ERR!find Python - "C:\Users\Rog�rio Chaves\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe"
could not be run
gyp ERR!find Python checking
if "python2"
can be used
gyp ERR!find Python - "python2"
is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR!find Python checking
if "python3"
can be used
gyp ERR!find Python - "python3"
is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR!find Python checking
if the py launcher can be used to find Python 2
gyp ERR!find Python - "py.exe"
is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR!find Python checking
if Python is C: \Python27\ python.exe
gyp ERR!find Python - "C:\Python27\python.exe"
could not be run
gyp ERR!find Python checking
if Python is C: \Python37\ python.exe
gyp ERR!find Python - "C:\Python37\python.exe"
could not be run
gyp ERR!find Python
gyp ERR!find Python ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **
  gyp ERR!find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
gyp ERR!find Python Node - gyp should be able to find and use Python.If not,
  gyp ERR!find Python you can
try one of the following options:
  gyp ERR!find Python - Use the
switch --python = "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR!find Python(accepted by both node - gyp and npm)
gyp ERR!find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR!find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
  gyp ERR!find Python npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR!find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
  gyp ERR!find Python https: //github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
  gyp ERR!find Python ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** ** **
  gyp ERR!find Python
gyp ERR!configure error
gyp ERR!stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
gyp ERR!stack at PythonFinder.fail(C: \Program Files\ nodejs\ node_modules\ npm\ node_modules\ node - gyp\ lib\ find - python.js: 307: 47)
gyp ERR!stack at PythonFinder.runChecks(C: \Program Files\ nodejs\ node_modules\ npm\ node_modules\ node - gyp\ lib\ find - python.js: 136: 21)
gyp ERR!stack at PythonFinder. < anonymous > (C: \Program Files\ nodejs\ node_modules\ npm\ node_modules\ node - gyp\ lib\ find - python.js: 225: 16)
gyp ERR!stack at PythonFinder.execFileCallback(C: \Program Files\ nodejs\ node_modules\ npm\ node_modules\ node - gyp\ lib\ find - python.js: 271: 16)
gyp ERR!stack at exithandler(child_process.js: 326: 5)
gyp ERR!stack at ChildProcess.errorhandler(child_process.js: 338: 5)
gyp ERR!stack at ChildProcess.emit(events.js: 376: 20)
gyp ERR!stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit(internal / child_process.js: 275: 12)
gyp ERR!stack at onErrorNT(internal / child_process.js: 467: 16)
gyp ERR!stack at processTicksAndRejections(internal / process / task_queues.js: 82: 21)
gyp ERR!System Windows_NT 10.0 .19042
gyp ERR!command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"
"C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"
"rebuild"
gyp ERR!cwd C: \Users\ Rogério Chaves\ OneDrive\ Área de Trabalho\ Node.Js\ node_modules\ dtrace - provider
gyp ERR!node - v v14 .17 .0
gyp ERR!node - gyp - v v5 .1 .0
gyp ERR!not ok
```

Estou tendo esse erro apos executar

```
npm install --save restify
```

eu pensei que era o powershell que não estava encontrando o python
eu adicionei o python em variaveis de sistema e mesmo assim persiste o erro

Answer (score 0):

Se está com o Python ok, tente o comando: `npm config set python python2.7`

Se não resolver, tente instalar o Visual Studio Build Tools:
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/pt-br/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools

Referência: https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#compiling-native-addon-modules